# Sorting the array of object in reducer state

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

I want to update the react state  using redux but data is not sorting correctly

**Original Array**

```
    "sections": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "user_id": 1,
            "field_type_id": 8,
            "section_id": 3,
            "value": "+96******",
            "type": "phone",
            "url": "tel:",
            "icon": "phone"
        }
     {
            "id": 9,
            "user_id": 1,
            "field_type_id": 8,
            "section_id": 3,
            "value": "test@gmail.com",
            "type": "email",
            "url": "",
            "icon": "email"
        }
    ]
```

I am updating the state using this code.

```
state = { ...state,sections :[ ...state.sections.filter(
                (section) => section.id !== action.payload.section.id
              ) , action.payload.section ]  }
            return state
```

After updating the array objects are getting reversed

```
   "sections": [
       {
            "id": 9,
            "user_id": 1,
            "field_type_id": 8,
            "section_id": 3,
            "value": "test@gmail.com",
            "type": "email",
            "url": "",
            "icon": "email"
        }
        {
            "id": 8,
            "user_id": 1,
            "field_type_id": 8,
            "section_id": 3,
            "value": "+91344******",
            "type": "phone",
            "url": "tel:",
            "icon": "phone"
        }
    ]
```

How can i stop the array reversing?

Comment: Can you show your state object and reducer in full?

Comment: I have updated the code . Please check . I am using filter to update "sections" but ut pushing object in last index.. how can i replace the index ?

Comment: @InderjitSIngh Normally you use `splice` for that. It not related to react or redux. It's just plain vanilla JS.

Comment: @super you don't mutate objects in react reducers. Filter preserves the order of the array so the problem is whatever the heck you are doing here `...state,sections :[ ...state.sections.filter(` ? Are you using a spread as an object key here ? I'm surprised this is even valid syntax.

Comment: Yeah agreed @nlta. It would be good to know what specifically are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why you add `action.payload.section` in the end of array after filter, filtering is enough for your use case ?

Comment: He is filtering out the id, and replacing it with the updated one. But he is placing the updated one at the end. So he need to use `splice` to place it in the right place... AFTER copying the array since you don't mutate it.

Comment: @super for splicing i need to first slice the index . It needed bit more work .

Comment: @InderjitSIngh No. Splicing can remove and insert at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply wanting to update an element at a specific index then just use `Array.prototype.map` to map the previous array to the next, updating the specific element when it's reached. Array order is maintained.

```
const nextState = {
  ...state,
  sections: state.sections.map(
    section => section.id === action.payload.section.id
      ? action.payload.section
      : section
  ),
};
return nextState;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of 2 :

```js
 // filter
  const state = {
    ...state,
    sections: state.sections.filter(
      (section) => section.id !== action.payload.section.id
    ),
  };
  
  // Update
  const state = {
    ...state,
    sections: state.sections.map((section) =>
      section.id !== action.payload.section.id
        ? { ...section, url: 'new Value' }
        : section
    ),
  };
```